# How to replace all 0s and all 1s from a pandas dataframe with random numbers?

Tags: python, pandas

There is a dataframe consisting of numbers 0 and 1. You need to replace all 0 with random numbers from the interval (0, 0.5), and all 1 with random numbers from the interval ( 1.0, 1.6). This must be done in all columns except the last column D.
df .replace does not help in this case, because the same number is generated for all 0s and the same number for all 1s.

I have it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.], 
                    'B': [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
                    'C': [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
                    'D': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]})
df:


     A     B     C    D
0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1
1   0.0   0.0   1.0   0
2   0.0   1.0   0.0   1
3   0.0   1.0   1.0   0
4   1.0   0.0   0.0   1
5   1.0   0.0   1.0   0
6   1.0   1.0   0.0   1
7   1.0   1.0   1.0   0
```

I need to get something like this:

```
        A              B         C        D
0   0.000021      0.246797   0.054679     1
1   0.002654      0.024675   1.075469     0
2   0.021457      1.012457   0.234678     1
3   0.065789      1.013468   1.345768     0
4   1.045679      0.125681   0.045794     1
5   1.018453      0.084673   1.457875     0
6   1.546877      1.015648   0.154677     1
7   1.423795      1.095642   1.012437     0
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`numpy.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html):

```
cols = ['A','B','C']

df[cols] = np.where(df[cols].eq(0), np.random.uniform(0, 0.6, size=(len(df), len(cols))), 
                                    np.random.uniform(1, 1.6, size=(len(df), len(cols)))) 
print (df)
          A         B         C  D
0  0.116624  0.019781  0.583289  1
1  0.523822  0.423117  1.069152  0
2  0.263680  1.080388  0.478821  1
3  0.344767  1.218203  1.318711  0
4  1.176945  0.312955  0.137224  1
5  1.064020  0.362695  1.010782  0
6  1.174818  1.458603  0.539392  1
7  1.369859  1.000210  1.459803  0
```